# How to check if attribute is not defined?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a playbook where I grab the metadata of an object in AWS S3 and register it to the `item_info` variable. If the `createddate` metadata key doesn't match a certain value, *or* if there is no `createddate` key, I want to download that file from a location via the `uri` module. Currently I'm having trouble with the "if there is no key" part.

Here's what the object looks like:

```json
{
  "changed": false,
  "failed": false,
  "object_info": [
    {
      "object_data": {
        "accept_ranges": "bytes",
        "content_length": 2760249,
        "content_type": "binary/octet-stream",
        "e_tag": "\\"0b82b2320d1d8ac226cd2720ccad554c\\"",
        "last_modified": "2023-05-15T16:32:27+00:00",
        "metadata": {
          "createddate": "2022-11-30T21:29:25.066Z"
        },
        "server_side_encryption": "AES256",
        "version_id": "SRehoPRyDbp.Rn2GKYXRE_40FzyLg4ek"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's the conditional I'm using:

```yaml
item_info.object_info | map(attribute='object_data.metadata.createddate') | first != item.history.createdDate
```

This works fine if there is a `createddate` key, but it fails if there isn't. I've tried this filter:

```yaml
item_info.object_info | map(attribute='object_data.metadata.createddate') is not defined or
item_info.object_info | map(attribute='object_data.metadata.createddate') | first != item.history.createdDate
```

But it throws the error:

> 'dict object' has no attribute 'createddate'

So what's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the value is not present, you can use `default` filter to provide that value:

```
(item_info.object_info | map(attribute='object_data.metadata.createddate') | first | default('') != item.history.createdDate) or
(item_info.object_info | map(attribute='object_data.metadata.createddate') | first is none)
```

Comment: Thanks! Your second method doesn't resolve to `true` when there is no `createddate` value (specifically the `item_info ... first is none` is still false when there's no `createddate`), but the first one seems to be working so I'll go with that one.

Answer (score 1):

Testing *`!= item.history.createdDate`* is sufficient if you use the default value

```yaml
  result: "{{ item_info.object_info|
              map(attribute='object_data.metadata.createddate')|
              first|default('') != item.history.createdDate }}"
```

See the below example for testing. You can use the option *default* of the filter [*map*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.map)

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    item_info:
      object_info:
      - object_data:
          metadata:
            createddate: '2022-11-30T21:29:25.066Z'
      - object_data:
          metadata:
            createddate: '2023-11-30T21:29:25.066Z'
      - object_data:
          metadata:
            dummy: '2023-11-30T21:29:25.066Z'

    test:
      - history:
          createdDate: '2023-11-30T21:29:25.066Z'

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ c2 }} (c1: {{ c1 }}, c2: {{ c2 }}, c1 or c2: {{ c3 }}) {{ cd }} "
      loop: "{{ objects }}"
      vars:
        objects: "{{ item_info.object_info }}"
        cd: "{{ item.object_data.metadata.createddate|d('undef') }}"
        c1: "{{ cd == 'undef' }}"
        c2: "{{ cd != test.0.history.createdDate }}"
        c3: "{{ (cd == 'undef') or (cd != test.0.history.createdDate) }}"

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ data.0 != item.history.createdDate }}
          {{ data.1 != item.history.createdDate }}
          {{ data.2 != item.history.createdDate }}
      loop: "{{ test }}"
      vars:
        data: "{{ item_info.object_info|
                  map(attribute='object_data.metadata.createddate', default='undef') }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
  msg: 'True (c1: False, c2: True, c1 or c2: True) 2022-11-30T21:29:25.066Z '
  msg: 'False (c1: False, c2: False, c1 or c2: False) 2023-11-30T21:29:25.066Z '
  msg: 'True (c1: True, c2: True, c1 or c2: True) undef '
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
  msg: |-
    True
    False
    True
```